# Having issues with a try statement, probably because I don't understand try

Tags: java, joptionpane

Trying to use `JFileChooser` to allow for editing of a file with strings in it.  In doing so I'm forced to use a `try` statement in order to catch any `IOException` errors.  I have a `BufferedReader` scanning the file and I've been able to successfully do everything I need to with the file (parsing wise).

The issue comes when I'm trying to get the user to select a certain 'item' to edit.  I forgot to mention the file being read has two fields, an Item Name and that items pricing.  Each line represents a new item.  I've been able to add the item name of each line to a `JComboBox` to allow the user to select the item to be edited.

I just can't seem to get my `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` to show up inside the try statement.  The only variation of `JOptionPane` I've gotten to work is the `.showInputDialog` but that adds a field I do not want.

What the hell is going on?  I know my syntax is correct for the `JOptionPane` because if I place it outside of the try statement it shows up fine (albiet without any of the information needed).  Is there a way to pass out my itemList that I get from the file in the `try` statement?  I was thinking via a method call but as I'm attempting this I'm putting this question up.

#### My Code

```
public class editItem extends JPanel{
    
    private Item item;
    private String filePath;
    private String[] itemList;
    private final JFormattedTextField name, price;
    private final FileNameExtensionFilter filter;
    private JFileChooser choose;
    private File file;
    private JComboBox cb;
    private findString findString;
    
    public editItem() throws FileNotFoundException{
        this.filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Item File", "ite");
        name = new JFormattedTextField();
        price = new JFormattedTextField();
        cb = new JComboBox();
        choose = new JFileChooser();
        choose.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        choose.setFileFilter(filter);
        cb.setEditable(false);
        startItemPanel();
    }
    
    private void startItemPanel() throws FileNotFoundException{
        int choice = choose.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{                  
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(choose.getSelectedFile()));
                    
                String line = br.readLine();
                int i = 0;
                while(line != null){
                    String[] parts = line.split("  ");
                    itemList[i]= line;
                    line = br.readLine();
                    item = new Item(parts[0], Double.parseDouble(parts[1]));
                    cb.addItem(item.getItemName());
                    i++;
                    
                    Object[] message = { "Select Item to Edit", cb,};     
                    int option= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, message, "Edit Item Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                        String selection = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
                        findString = new findString(itemList, selection);
                        edit();
                    } 
                 }
                
                    
             }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
        
    }

    private void edit() {
        name.setValue(itemList[findString.find()]);
        name.setValue(itemList[findString.find()+1]);
        Object[] message = {
          "Item Name", name,
          "Item Price", price,    
        };
        int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, message, "New Customer Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
            item = new Item(name.getText(), Double.parseDouble(price.getText()));
            try{
                filePath = choose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();;
                if (!filePath.matches(".*\\.ite$")){
                    filePath += ".ite";
                }
                file = new File(filePath);                
                try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath, false)){
                    int length = itemList.length;
                    for (int i = 0; i < (length); i++){
                        fw.write(itemList[i]);
                        i++;
                        fw.write("  " + itemList[i]);
                        fw.write("\n");
                    }
                }
            }catch (IOException ex){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

I attempted putting the first `JOptionPane` into my `edit()` method and passed through the `JComboBox` and `itemList` from the `try` statement (outside the `while` loop), nothing.

I should add when I say nothing, I mean nothing happens.  I have my `Driver` class calling the `editItem` class with an `actionListener` on a `JButton`, I realize this is not a `main` class.

Also my `edit` method isn't completely finished, forgot to work out adding the user input into the edited item!

Comment: You could have posted the exception trace instead of that long explanation

Comment: @Stunner there is not an error being thrown, just nothing happens.

Comment: I think it's not finding the parent correctly. Please try JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Test", "Edit Item Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); Is it working? If not then try 
"null" in place of "this".

Comment: @Deepak213 woops read that wrong, no nothing occurs.  Just keeps running.

Comment: @Deepak213 I just find it weird that I can get it to work perfectly fine with the `showInputDialog` method of `JOptionPane`, just everything else has issues.  And the `showInputDialog` only works if it's me adding the `JComboBox` as the `Object`, if I attempt to use the contstructor that has it's own variation of multiple values to select it also doesn't show up

Comment: @Deepak213 so apparently I was throwing every exception (thought I'd specified `IOException` but whatever haha.  Because I was catching every one it wouldn't pass through the for loop even.  thanks for the help

Comment: @Deepak213 And the error it was catching was something to do with setting my String array itemList to the string line.  Gonna have to go another approach.

Comment: Yeah in second argument of JOptionPane.